# Can someone explains why this code prints 4?

Tags: c++

The output of this code is `4`, and I don't understand why. Can someone please explain why?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
int main(){
    int val = 1;

    do{
        val++;
        ++val;

    }while (val++ > 25);
    cout << val << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Well, because 4 < 25 and you increment `val` 3 times.

Comment: @Bob__ because 4 <= 25 if you wanna get all exact about it.

Comment: A quick run through with your debugger would be very insightful.

Comment: @George Fair enough, let's say because `3 > 25` is `false`.

Comment: Do you think the output should be something different? If so, explain why you think so.

Comment: Down voting because you think a person should know something is not a good reason to down vote.  This guy put together an example and asked a solid question.  He just doesn't understand the code he has, which is where we all started (if we can only remember back that far) :)

Comment: TBH, this seems a typographical error. Condition should be `<` or `<=`, not `>`. If it is something else than typo, the asker should explain enough to make this clear.

Comment: @Edwin I doubt such trivial and _"niche"_ stuff determining from basic misconceptions is really useful for future researchers. Lack of debugging efforts is what's making that question VLQ, and deserving a downvote.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Pretend for a moment that you really don't have the skills to answer the above question.  Now keeping that level of skill in mind, exactly how likely are you going to have the skills to run a debugger?  How are you going to be able to alter your approach to figure it out?  Like I said, we all start somewhere, and typically we move out of that somewhere with a guide.  After a while, the guide becomes unnecessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With a do while loop you will execute the body of a loop once, and then evaluate the while condition to see if you should do it again.  That means you do

```
val++;
++val;
```

making `val` `3`, and then you do `val++` in the condition statement.  that makes `val` `4`, but it returns `3` since it is a post-increment expression and since `3` is not greater than `25`, you exit the loop.  This is why `val` has the value of `4`.

Answer (score 3):

```
int val = 1;         // val is 1

do{
    val++;           // val is 2 after statement
    ++val;           // val is 3 after statement

}while (val++ > 25); // val is 3 within expression
                     // 3 > 25 is false so while loop exits.
                     // --
                     // After the expression
                     // val incremented with postfix ++ to 4.

cout << val << endl; // print val (which is 4)
```

Comment: _`value is 4`_ Why so exactly? Explain please.

Comment: Nitpick: condition will use `val` value 3, because it's postfix `++`.

Answer (score 1):

In the line `int val = 1;` `val` will be set to 1. in the line `val++;` and in the line `++val;`, `val` will be incremented, so after both, `val` will be set to 3.

Now, probably, you *meant* `while (val++ < 25)`, but you *wrote*`while (val++ > 25)`. So, `val++` will be incremented to 4, but yield 3 due to being post-inrement, and the comparison `3 > 25` will yield `false`, meaning, the loop won't loop.

After that, you print val which is 4.

Assuming, you are new to C++, I also want to hint you towards NOT using `using namespace std;` but instead writing the `std::` before cout. Namespaces were introduced to prevent conflicting symbol names in libraries etc and pulling all symbols into global namespace with `using namespace std;` actually completely circumvents the goal behind namespaces.

Comment: in the case of "while (val++ < 25)" the output is 28

Comment: Would you expect anything else? What is the goal you are reaching for?

Answer (score 1):

Value of Val will increase by 2 within do at the very first time, and the while checking the condition within while block of do while, its value get increased by 1.  i.e while(4>25). Hence value of Val will be 4.

Comment: Fisrt var initialized with 1, after that post increment and pre increment. Here its value is 3. Now in while here it is also have post increment. So finaly it's value will be 4.

Answer (score 1):

You're incrementing the val in the body twice, then it increments again where you put while.

```
int main(){
int val = 1;

do{
    val++; // val = 2
    ++val; // val = 3

}while (val++ // val = 4 > 25); // then breaks the loop because 4 < 25.
cout << val << endl;

return 0;
}
```